# Ipython Notebook & Matplotlib: How to wrap a plot within a html div?

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I want to add some `css` to part of my plot, (specifically, I want to set `float:left`).

How can I produce the plot within a div, so I can use `css` to control its layout?

For example, for code

```
def simple_plot(ax = None):
    if ax is None:
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    a = [1,2,3,4]
    b = [3,4,5,6]
    plt.plot(a, b,'-', color='black')

simple_plot()
```

The default output html in `Ipython Notebook` is

```
<div class="output_area">
  <div class="prompt"></div>
  <div class="output_subarea output_png">
    <img src="data:image/png;>
```

For some plots, I want to wrap it with a html/css, something like this:

```
<div class="output_area">
  <div class="prompt"></div>
  <div class="output_subarea output_png">
    <div class="custom-css-for-matplotlib"> ## custom html/css code wrapper
```

How can I do that?

It would be fantastic if I can simply code in cell like:

```
<div class='custom css class'>
simple_plot()
</div>
```

Comment: Would you consider an alternative solution of using javascript to select the parent of all `img` tags and for those parents to set their styling dynamically via javascript? Or, why not simply add more styling properties to the css of the already present class "output_png"? After all, the `div` is already there, why not use it?

Comment: @OliverW., I may not be clear, I want to add `html/css` wraps to **certain plots**, not all plots.