# IPython Notebook & Pandas: How does pandas produce html table?

Tags: python, pandas, ipython, jupyter

The output of `pandas` `dataframe` is an `HTML table`, I want to know how it produce the html into `Ipython Notebook`?

[image]

```
<div class="output_subarea output_html rendered_html output_result">
  <div>
   <table class="dataframe" border="1">
     <thead>
       <tr style="text-align: right">
```

Because I also want to **wrap my output with some html**, I want to know how.
([Ipython Notebook & Matplotlib: How to wrap a plot within a html div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35425743/ipython-notebook-matplotlib-how-to-wrap-a-plot-within-a-html-div))

I'm now digging the source code at: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/2d51b33066e5991913dcba2cfb93d2112a2e8a8f/pandas/core/format.py

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In IPython you can display arbitrary HTML by importing ipython's display module. Pandas can convert a `DataFrame` to html which you can then apply your updates to, e.g.:

```
import pandas as pd
from IPython import display
df = pd.DataFrame(...)
display.HTML(df.to_html())
```

Should display the same html table as above.

`DataFrame.to_html()` returns a http string, so you can do simple string manipulation to wrap your text:

```
display.HTML('<div style="visibility:hidden">'+df.to_html()+'</div>')
```

Would hide the table.

Comment: So in sum, it just produces `string` and then formated in `HTML` with `display`. This answered this question. But my concern (wrap `plot` with `html`) still remain unanswered, because there is no way I can produce image in string. That's really sad....