# In a Jupyter notebook, is it possible to set the maximum height of an IPython.display.Image?

Tags: python, html, css, jupyter-notebook, nbconvert

I am attempting to plot images in JupyterLab via [`IPython.display.Image`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html#IPython.display.Image).

Is there a way to make some (but not all) images have a bounded maximum height?

This class has a constructor:

`__init__(data=None, url=None, filename=None, format=None, embed=None, width=None, height=None, retina=False, unconfined=False, metadata=None)`

The constructor has a `height` and `width` argument. These control `<img src="" height="" width="">`.

But only the `width` actually applies to HTML. The `height` has no effect, because Jupyter includes custom CSS `.jp-RenderedImage img { ... height: auto; ... }`

Another idea was to first render the image to HTML, then wrap the HTML image in a div which sets `max-height` for all images inside it. However I don't know how to achieve this. And `Image._repr_html_()` returns None if the Image contains base64 embedded contents.

[Ipython Notebook & Matplotlib: How to wrap a plot within a html div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35425743/ipython-notebook-matplotlib-how-to-wrap-a-plot-within-a-html-div) went unanswered as well.